# Recoverable SD Card?

Tags: sd-card, format

I have an apparently corrupted 128Gb SD Card. I do not care about the data (it was backed-up), but I would like to be able to reformat it and use it.

I tried under linux, without much success:

```
root@rennes:~# blkid | grep exfat
/dev/sde1: UUID="896E-A113" TYPE="exfat" PTTYPE="dos"
root@rennes:~# mount /dev/sde1 /mnt/usb
FUSE exfat 1.2.8
WARN: volume was not unmounted cleanly.
root@rennes:~# ls -lh /mnt/usb
total 128K
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 128K Oct 19 06:53 Kiwix
root@rennes:~# umount /dev/sde1

root@rennes:~# mkfs.fat /dev/sde1
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
root@rennes:~# mount /dev/sde1 /mnt/usb
FUSE exfat 1.2.8
WARN: volume was not unmounted cleanly.
root@rennes:~# ls -lh /mnt/usb
total 128K
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 128K Oct 19 06:53 Kiwix
root@rennes:~# umount /dev/sde1

root@rennes:~# parted /dev/sde
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sde
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) mklabel msdos
Warning: The existing disk label on /dev/sde will be destroyed and all data on this disk will be
lost. Do you want to continue?
Yes/No? Yes                                                               
(parted) mkpart primary fat32 1MiB 100%                                   
(parted) set 1 boot on                                                    
(parted) quit                                                             
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.
root@rennes:~# mkfs.fat /dev/sde1                                     
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
root@rennes:~# mount /dev/sde1 /mnt/usb
FUSE exfat 1.2.8
WARN: volume was not unmounted cleanly.
root@rennes:~# umount /dev/sde1
```

etc... Even **dd** is hopeless.

I finally tried the formater tool from SD Card Association (http://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter), and got the following error message:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MzNR.png)

(*Edit:*

```
Invalid end of sector signature: 0x2DB6
exfat_check_validate_boot_sector returned error: 22 (invalid argument)
Initializing cached values failed: 22 (invalid argument)
Generated invalid volume. exfat_check_validate_boot_sector returned error: 22 (invalid argument)
```

)

**So, my question is: can I format my SD card? How? Or should I just throw it away...**

Thanks,

Comment: Throw it away is right.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting with Windows and if that fails (as it likely will) throw it away. Such cards are reasonably inexpensive enough, they do not warrant a lot of time spent on them